# How to select a different webcam using cv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to stream live video from an external camera using cv2. I was able to write the simple code to stitch the frames and stream it. But am struggling to find how to change the camera.

I tried to run it after disabling the main webcam from the task manager, but it still did not work.
So, if anyone can help me with some clue regarding the same, that would be a great help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Cameras are numbered for Windows. You can try a few indeces and check which camera index belongs to the camera you want.

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
```